# android - how to set floating action button gravity from right to left programmatically

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have a floating action button. I want to change its gravity from right to left with help of my java code.

[image]

Comment: What layout you are using as the parent? Share the xml code

Answer (score 0):

There is no any such methods to set the floating action button in left side. You can look at the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RelativeLayout as parent you can set the gravity like this,

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
```

Comment: Not xml. I want to change using java.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CoordinatorLayout you can set de gravity like this,

```
app:layout_anchorGravity="top|start"
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem like you. And I solved it using LayoutParams. Here is the code.

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) this.mFab.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.BOTTOM;
this.mFab.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```